# AndroidStudio: add virtual folder in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I use the build.gradle file to collect several folders on my computer in my app's asset folder:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['../someFolder/', 'src/main/assets']
    }
}
```

This leads to my asset folder having the files of `someFolder` and the "original" asset folder:

```
//The "physical" folders

../someFolder
  |- file1.txt
  |- file2.txt
  |- file3.txt
src/main/assets
  |- asset1.txt

//...become this:

assets
  |- file1.txt
  |- file2.txt
  |- file3.txt
  |- asset1.txt
```

How can I redirect the paths in gradle so that my asset folder contains a folder "someFolder" with all the files from `someFolder`, e.g:

```
assets
  |- someFolder
  |--- file1.txt
  |--- file2.txt
  |--- file3.txt
  |- asset1.txt
```

Comment: Virtual folder as a folder that does not really exist or virtual as in we can "override" this later?

Comment: virtual as in "does not really exist".

Comment: I don't think this is something gradle alone can achieve. If you are on a Linux machine or a Mac, you could work with symlinks. There should be a way to trigger a command to create a symlink from your source to your destination folder @ gradle's configuration time via the Exec task https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Answer (score 1):

1) Create folder inside of the project as your external assets `./extAssets`

```
sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', './extAssets']
```

2) Link all your external directories inside this folder

```
$ cd extAssets/
$ ln -s ../../someFolder/ someFolder
```

As result you will see

```
assets
  |- someFolder
  |--- file1.txt
  |--- file2.txt
  |--- file3.txt
  |- asset1.txt
```

without any file copying

Comment: nice idea for Linux! Unfortunately it's not platform-independent (or to phrase it differently: there is no solution for Windows)